# appcompat 21 logo as back button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

After update sdk to 21 version logo doesn't display. I display logo using following code:

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

The code looks:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAWIx.png

[image]

This code:

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Looks:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkYqa.png

[image]

This code:

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Looks:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ssw2A.png

[image]

My logo doesn't display as back button.

How me make old style as here? https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKOz4.png

**Note:** Sorry, I didn't notice similar questions. =(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [Toolbar documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html):

> - *A title and subtitle.* The title should be a signpost for the Toolbar's current position in the navigation hierarchy and the content contained there. The subtitle, if present should indicate any extended information about the current content. **If an app uses a logo image it should strongly consider omitting a title and subtitle.**
>
> In modern Android UIs developers should lean more on a visually distinct color scheme for toolbars than on their application icon. **The use of application icon plus title as a standard layout is discouraged on API 21 devices and newer.**

However, if you want an application icon, [setLogo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html#setLogo(int)) is indeed the correct method.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me if using an icon

```
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_app_icon);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Or, if you want a wider logo

```
actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_app_logo);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thank you, it took me forever to find this.