# ActionBar not showing Icon in API 21

Tags: java, android

Today I upgraded to API 21, the biggest mistake in this month.

So I spent the whole day trying to get an action bar icon.

I´m using eclipse with sdk and everthing is updated.

The problem is the following:

Before API 21, I added an icon with

```
android.app.ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
```

That worked fine, all the time...
But now, unfortunately, this lines cause a Nullpointer Exception...

**(Attach 1)**

So I can get the actionbar only with:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

and thats the breaking point.. This actionBar doesnt set the icon, the method setIcon isnt working at all.

So, to find a solution, I have completely re installed Eclipse and the sdk and started a new android Project. In this new Project there is also no ActionBar Icon, and the code above also not works.

This leads me to the assumption, that this is some new API 21 bug.

Below i posted some additional informations:

Imports:

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuInflater;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.view.Window;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.CheckBox;
 import android.widget.CompoundButton;
 import android.widget.ImageButton;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.ProgressBar;
 import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
```

***Styles:***

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go      here. -->
</style>
 <style name="Theme_Translucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
<item name="android:background">#3798db</item>

</style>




</resources>
```

**Logcat with first Code (Attach 1), Sorry for bad layout:**

```
     erere`11-15 22:33:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(2663): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      11-15 22:33:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(2663): Process: com.lunation.kuhdwallpaper,  PID:  2663
     11-15 22:33:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(2663): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     start activity     ComponentInfo{com.lunation.kuhdwallpaper/com.lunation.kuhdwallpaper.MainActivity}:   java.lang.NullPointerException
      11-15 22:33:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):   at    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
     11-15 22:33:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
     11-15 22:33:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
    11-15 22:33:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
    11-15 22:33:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    11-15 22:33:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    11-15 22:33:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
    11-15 22:33:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-15 22:33:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    11-15 22:33:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
   11-15 22:33:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
   11-15 22:33:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):  at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
    11-15 22:33:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-15 22:33:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(2663): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    11-15 22:33:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):     at com.lunation.kuhdwallpaper.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:198)
    11-15 22:33:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):     at   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    11-15 22:33:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    11-15 22:33:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
   11-15 22:33:35.910: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):  ... 12 more
`

    11-15 22:33:35.790: I/dalvikvm(2663): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted

    11-15 22:33:35.790: I/dalvikvm(2663): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
```

The project uses appcompat v7,v4.

Does anybody got a advice?

Greetings?

Comment: The action bar no longer has an icon by default with `Theme.Material` or `Theme.AppCompat` (in the latter case, if you are using version 21.+).

Comment: So, how do you get an actionbar icon?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642378/appcompat-21-logo-as-back-button

Comment: Thanks that works, but it is really confusing that google didnt mark setIcon() as deprecated.

Comment: @user3826600 this is just a new design guide, nothing more.

Comment: But the method setIcon(), isnt working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

at the end of each item
add the item like below

  `<!-- Support library compatibility-->
  <item name="background">#3798db</item>`

And you can custom your actionbar. It works to me.